# What is wrong with this plunker code?

Tags: angularjs

I have been trying to get a simple AngularJs code running on Plunker but seems like I'm doing something wrong.

Can you please tell what I'm missing over here?

https://plnkr.co/edit/blY85rvARIqkmfCnRBOV?p=preview

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-snapshot/angular2.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
      <dependency></dependency>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
// Code goes here
angular.module('myApp', 'dependency');

angular.
module('dependency', []).
component('dependency', {
  templateUrl: 'dependency.html',
  controller: ['$scope', function dependencyController($scope) {
    $scope.dependencyScopedVariable = "Some local variabled of dependency";
  }]
});
```

dependency.html

```
<div>{{dependencyScopedVariable}}</div>
```

Comment: You are sourcing [Angular2](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/) but you write code in [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api)

Comment: @koox00 Updated, still no result

Comment: `angular.module('myApp', ['dependancy'])` declares a module

Comment: Holy cow! Silly mistake, thanks a lot @koox00 !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update, fixed - see [this plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/qogBLvLoOvfR5uEr9Uxn?p=preview).

#### View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
      <dependency></dependency>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### script.js

```
// Code goes here

// Code goes here
angular.module('myApp', ['dependency']);
angular.module('dependency', []).
component('dependency', {
  templateUrl: 'dependency.html',
  controller: ['$scope', function dependencyController($scope) {
    $scope.dependencyScopedVariable = "Some local variabled of dependency";
  }] 
})
```

Comment: Okay, but I see that you have combined the myApp and dependency module. I do not intend to do that.

Comment: @ShaaradDalvi updated, now your second module dependency is injected into myApp. Btw. thanks for downvoting while helping you.

Comment: I didn't downvote! I upvoted it actually. Marking this as answer as well just so you don't feel bad :)

Comment: @lin I upvoted also, had to say it since we are sharing :)